# How to manage a SQL database for use with a Forms Authentication web site from another web site that is using Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have a SQL database (call it UserStore) that is used with a Forms Authentication web site.  It was created with aspnet_regsql with features for SqlMembershipProvider and SqlRoleProvider.

I want to manage that SQL database from a web site that uses Windows Authentication, WebSiteAdmin.  However, the RoleManager appears to prevent a Windows user from accessing the WebSiteAdmin web site.

**Attempt A**
I added a "roleManager" and "membership" section to the web.config file for the WebSiteAdmin web site (.NET Framework 4.5.1) with all the proper information.  However, I cannot access the WebSiteAdmin web site.  I am prompted for credentials, enter valid credentials for a Windows user, but they are not accepted.  I believe this is because the system does not recognize the user as a member of a role that can access the web site because it is checking against the roles in the UserStore database.  It should be checking to see if it is a member of a Windows group.

**Attempt B**
Then I tried just adding a "membership" section to the web.config file and I can access the web site without being prompted for credentials.  However, when I access the web page that displays users and roles from the UserStore database, I get this error.

> The Role Manager feature has not been enabled

The statement causing the error is

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(sUserName);
```

I am sure the database, role manager, and membership provider are all correct, as they are used in another Forms Authentication web site without problems.

How can I access the WebSiteAdmin web site without being subject to the RoleManager?

Thanks for your help.